# How can I remove last * from each "organisations": value from the string without using JSON.parse() and remove last , from [] using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
let abc = '[{"userid":"88623619","organisations":"Imperial College London*Imperial College Healthcare NHS Trust*Imperial College Healthcare NHS Trust*Imperial College Healthcare NHS Trust*Milton Keynes Hospital NHS Foundation Trust*","oversightGroupRole":"Chair","oversightGroupMemberName":"Dr Ahmed Ahmed","oversightGroupType":"Steering Committee"},{"userid":"88624025","organisations":"Bangor University*Barnet, Enfield and Haringey Mental Health NHS Trust*Cambridge University Hospitals NHS Foundation Trust*","oversightGroupRole":"Public Member","oversightGroupMemberName":"Professor b b","oversightGroupType":"Advisory Group"},{"userid":"88623985","organisations":"Aberdeen And District Fibromyalgia Support Group*Additive Design Ltd*Altnagelvin Area Hospital*Ataxia UK*Tameside Hospital NHS Foundation Trust*","oversightGroupRole":"Chair","oversightGroupMemberName":"Chief TestTestRr TestTestRr","oversightGroupType":"Data Monitoring Committee"},]';
```

the Desried Result is

```js
abc = '[{"userid":"88623619","organisations":"Imperial College London*Imperial College Healthcare NHS Trust*Imperial College Healthcare NHS Trust*Imperial College Healthcare NHS Trust*Milton Keynes Hospital NHS Foundation Trust","oversightGroupRole":"Chair","oversightGroupMemberName":"Dr Ahmed Ahmed","oversightGroupType":"Steering Committee"},{"userid":"88624025","organisations":"Bangor University*Barnet, Enfield and Haringey Mental Health NHS Trust*Cambridge University Hospitals NHS Foundation Trust","oversightGroupRole":"Public Member","oversightGroupMemberName":"Professor b b","oversightGroupType":"Advisory Group"},{"userid":"88623985","organisations":"Aberdeen And District Fibromyalgia Support Group*Additive Design Ltd*Altnagelvin Area Hospital*Ataxia UK*Tameside Hospital NHS Foundation Trust","oversightGroupRole":"Chair","oversightGroupMemberName":"Chief TestTestRr TestTestRr","oversightGroupType":"Data Monitoring Committee"},]';
```

My Code which is not working:

```js
let abc = '[{"userid":"88623619","organisations":"Imperial College London*Imperial College Healthcare NHS Trust*Imperial College Healthcare NHS Trust*Imperial College Healthcare NHS Trust*Milton Keynes Hospital NHS Foundation Trust*","oversightGroupRole":"Chair","oversightGroupMemberName":"Dr Ahmed Ahmed","oversightGroupType":"Steering Committee"},{"userid":"88624025","organisations":"Bangor University*Barnet, Enfield and Haringey Mental Health NHS Trust*Cambridge University Hospitals NHS Foundation Trust*","oversightGroupRole":"Public Member","oversightGroupMemberName":"Professor b b","oversightGroupType":"Advisory Group"},{"userid":"88623985","organisations":"Aberdeen And District Fibromyalgia Support Group*Additive Design Ltd*Altnagelvin Area Hospital*Ataxia UK*Tameside Hospital NHS Foundation Trust*","oversightGroupRole":"Chair","oversightGroupMemberName":"Chief TestTestRr TestTestRr","oversightGroupType":"Data Monitoring Committee"},]';

    abc = abc.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, '');

    let startIndex = 0;
    while ((startIndex = abc.indexOf('"organisations":', startIndex)) !== -1) {    
        let endIndex = abc.indexOf('*', startIndex + '"organisations":'.length);
        if (endIndex !== -1) {       
            abc = abc.slice(0, endIndex) + abc.slice(endIndex + 1);
        }
        startIndex += '"organisations":'.length;
    }

    console.log(abc);
```

Please not the values inside the string are all dynamic.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while ? 

Comment: Why don't you want to use `JSON.parse()`? It's generally a bad idea to try to process JSON strings directly.

Comment: Because sometimes properties values can be array in the form of [{},{},] e,g oversightGroupType property can be "abc" or [{name: aaa, status: "abc"},{name: bbb, status: "zzz"},]

Comment: Think you need to escape the * 
(e.g. \\*) if you want it to act as a literal match . But that's a guess lol

Comment: @KarimAli Really you should start by fixing the application that generates the invalid JSON text. Or use an extended JSON parser that supports trailing commas and unquoted strings.